# ASP.NET MVC4 Validation Error - Whats wrong

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have a validation error being thrown in Firefox and IE, but not chrome.

I'm stuck and don't know where to look to find out what it does not like

My Model

```
public class Appointment
{
  [Required]
  public string DateString { get; set; }
  ..
}
```

The page

```
<link href="~/Content/CSS/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input class="form-control date datetime" type="text" value="@Model.DateString" name="DateString" data-min-view="2" data-date-format="dd-M-yyyy" id="DateString">
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DateString)
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-rad" id="" title="Save"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>

<script src="~/Content/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The browser

(Before submit)

```
<input class="form-control date datetime" value="04-Feb-2015" id="DateString" name="DateString" data-min-view="2" data-date-format="dd-M-yyyy" type="text">
```

So when I press submit it will not post as sets the focus back on the text box

```
<input aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="DateString-error" class="form-control date datetime input-validation-error" value="04-Feb-2015" id="DateString" name="DateString" data-min-view="2" data-date-format="dd-M-yyyy" type="text">
```

So how do I figure out whats wrong?

Comment: You generating your html for the property manually! There is nothing in your html which relates at all to using unobtrusive validation, and in any case your using a string for a date so not sure what kind of validation your expecting. Why are you not using html helpers to generate the control so this all works out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

Can you F12 and validate that you are loading the files required to fire the client side validation.

```
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js
jquery.validate.min.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
```

Also you can decorate your model with a required field display annotation and see if the browser will pick that up.

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
 public string FieldName{ get; set; }
```